# Dockerfile env dependent starting point

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Picking up docker, a little late to the show, but better late than never.

Following a few online tutorials i landed at a docker file and docker-compose for my 1st microservice node+mongo.

Terrible setup for dev so now will implement trusty pm2: https://dev.to/itmayziii/step-by-step-guide-to-setup-node-with-docker-2mc9

Production would want the below, but dev i would want pm2 instance mgr to reboot on file change..

But the obvious question i now have is how to differentiate between dev and prod in the Dockerfile?

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm i
COPY . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 3000
CMD node ./build/server.js
```

docker-compose

```
version: "3"

services:

  ms-authentication-service:
    image: "ms-authentication-image"
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    links:
      - mongodb
    networks:
      - default
    ports:
      - "8080:8000"
    restart: always

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.2
    container_name: "ms-authentication-mongo-image"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: bob
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: bob
    networks:
      - default
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

Comment: with environment variables https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables

Comment: Why would you be changing files inside the container for development? Are you developing this app while it is *inside* a container? I don't follow your use case.

Comment: During dev i would want to run my `pm2.dev.config.js` which watches the file built files which allows development without restarting docker. Where as on prod i would want to run simply `node ./build/server.js`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone would this not demand that i also then have to use docker-compose on production? This i do not need as in production the mongodb is a service elsewhere not in the container thus i would not want to run docker compose.

Comment: Or should I have 1 setup in the compose and 1 in the dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, managing environment like the staging or production based on ENV is common practice, but in the case of Docker the best approach is `tag`.

It's better to use `tag` for `dev, stage and production` in case of Docker. There are many reasons, one reason is `mount code` in development environment is fine but it is not recommended in the production environment.

> When building images, always `tag` them with useful tags which codify
>   version information, intended destination `(prod or test, for
>   instance)`, stability, or other information that is useful when
>   deploying the application in different environments. **Do not rely on
>   the automatically-created latest tag**.

[image]
[Docker App development best-practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/dev-best-practices/)

But if still want to go with ENV approach then you can use the docker-entrypoint script.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN npm install pm2 -g
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
ENV NODE_ENV=development
RUN chmod +x docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT  ["sh","docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Docker-entrypoint

```
 #!bin/sh 
     if [ $NODE_ENV = development ]; then
     pm2 start server.js
     else
     node server.js
    fi
```

So you are good to go  and you will able to change this in Dockerfile or run time

```
 docker run --env NODE_ENV=production -it --rm node:production
```

or

```
 docker run --env NODE_ENV=development -it --rm dev
```